# UIViewController does not respond to rotation function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a View Controller embedded in a Navigation Controller,

In my view controller I have defined the function,

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
```

I also do this inside the function,

```
[super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
```

But when I run it on my device the call never reaches here? What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The NavigationController propably receives that call

Comment: But I have embedded it in the default navigation controller using the storyboard.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Execute your own code when the device is rotated?

Answer (score 1):

If the call never reaches the function then check this method `supportedInterfaceOrientations` .

Probably other interface orientations are masked.

Comment: I should check this in my View Controller but my view controller by default is   embedded in a navigation controller

Comment: Check for this function in navigation Controller or appDelegate

Comment: I subclassed the UINavigationController class and set the supportedInterfaceOrientations as UIOrientationMaskAll, the call still does not reach!

Comment: OK. Does you screen rotate when you rotate your device ?

Comment: Yeah the screen does rotate

Answer (score 0):

if you want to rotate the view you can also do this by using this method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
       return YES;
}
```